# Java Analytics API or Open Sources

Tags: java, analytics

Is there any java API or open source to build data aggregation, group by and analytics on top of list of object data?

Strategy should be:

1. Cache data in memory
2. Process and Calculate group by totals

Comment: You should accept one of the answers to your question, so that the bounty goes to him

Answer (score 6):

I believe what you are looking for is BIRT, never used it myself though.

Here is a link...

http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/

Answer (score 3):

As API I recommend [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/).

Other known tools which maybe you can use as API or include the libraries since they are open source:

- [WEKA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/): Weka loads all the data in memory and work on them in memory (which might also cause a problem if your data is very large).
- [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/)
- [RapidMiner](http://www.rapidminer.com/)

Answer (score 3):

You might try to use jxpath: http://commons.apache.org/jxpath/  this allow you to browse through java objects using x path queries using this you can select all objects in the list which have object with propery value = "abcd" . Using xpath you can also use functions like  sum avg ...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind writing Clojure (a Lisp that runs on the JVM), then Incanter might be an interesting option.

- Web site: http://incanter.org/
- Cheat sheet (pdf): http://incanter.org/docs/incanter-cheat-sheet.pdf